# Specific Filter in Magento

Tags: magento

For a Magento webshop I want te create a filter.

This filter looks like:

Dropdown 1: Brand name
Dropdown 2: Product name

After filtering with the dropdowns it shows only the related product of product name from dropdown 2.

### Do anyone know how to create this filter?

Sorry for late response,

It is for a floor.

Every floor has its own plint.

So When I make a relation between a floor and a plint, the plint must shown at the productpage of floor. Thats easy to setup. 
But when I go to the category page of the plint I must quick filter to the plint, so first customer can setup the brand of floor and second the all the floors must be showed of that brand ( with ajax), when the user choose the product floor from second dropdown, the plints must be shown that is matching the product.

So I don't know how to set it up and how I start. Maybe there is such a simple solution or plugin to set it up.

Comment: Please define "create this filter" more precisely. It's unclear whether you need help with filtering a collection for a given attribute (Database), or help with the setup of cascading dropdowns (PHP/Ajax), or both, or s/t else. Besides that, it would be helpful to see any of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I just edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by using the extension : Products parts filter by Amasty